# CodeIgniter - mysql while loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, templates

I am relatively experienced PHP developer.

I have chosen the CodeIgniter framework. So far I have understood how it is used. Until now, I want to be able to do a while loop.

Within my controller I have:

```
$this->load->model('Test');
$data['result'] = $this->Test->getInfo();
$this->load->view('index1', $data);
```

In my Model I have:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name='Hart'")or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );    
return $row;
```

And in my View:

```
echo $result[0];
```

However, this only outputs the first field within the first row found.

Please could you help me with retrieving the information from a database - while loop.

Does the while loop happen in the Model? Am I just echoing out the result correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's actually a much easier way to do what you want to do using the ActiveRecord class that CodeIgniter includes which will allow you to just return an array of results. Here's the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select).

Your model would become:

```
$this->db->where('last_name','Hart');
$result = $this->db->get('users');
return $result->result_array();
```

You may also have to setup your database in `application/config/database.php`, and also load the database class in `application/config/autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

To display this information, using the MVC pattern properly your controller should pass the information it gets from the model to a view. To do this generally you do this:

```
$data['myinfo'] = $this->test->getInfo();
$this->load->view('test_view',$data);
```

Then you have to create a view like so in `applications/views/test_view.php`:

```
<h1>Some HTML goes here</h1>
<?php
foreach($myinfo as $row) {
    echo $row['field'];
}
?>
<p>Some more HTML goes here</p>
```

I suggest you read the [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) before diving into creating an application as CodeIgniter includes libraries that greatly simplify and speed up the whole process.

Comment: Ok great! Where do I declare the db connection details? And do i echo it out the same then?

Comment: I just threw that information in the post and I'm about to edit it again to add information on displaying that info properly.

Comment: @hart1994 - read the documentation for db connection details!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has worked without any problems. Thanks for your time. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well mysql_fetch_array will only bring back one row at a time, so you would need to put the while loop around the mysql_fetch_array call

Something like

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     //save/process data
     }`

I would however just use codeigniters libraries to load the db and then use it:

`$this->load->database();

     $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name='Hart'");

     $result = $result->result_array();

     //check for data and handle errors

     return $result[0]`